Were any women from the First Estate at the Estates-General of 1789?
Famously, women of the Third Estate were not invited to participate in the Estates-General of 1789. This led to their petition to the King, and later the March on Versailles.
The situation for the elections to the Estates-General was similar. By the rules issued in the Edict of January 1789, I understand that women of the First and Second Estates were able to vote for representatives, but those of the Third Estate were not.
I am not aware of any women from the nobility who were elected as representatives. However, was this true of the First Estate? In particular, that Estate was defined to include all higher clergy, including e.g. abbesses and prioresses of the various convents around France.
Were women from the First Estate (a) eligible to election as representatives of the First Estate, and (b) if so, did this happen?
Elaboration on the Edict:
Reading through the rules of the edict for clergy, Article IX reads in part:

Lesdits baillis et sénéchaux principaux ... feront assigner ... les évêques et les abbés, tous les chapitres, corps et communautés ecclésiastiques rentes, réguliers et séculiers, des deux sexes, et généralement tous les ecclésiastiques possédant bénéfice ou commanderie ... à l’effet de comparaître à rassemblée générale du bailliage...

Which I would translate as

The said bailiffs and principal seneschals ... shall assign ... the bishops and abbots, all the endowed [i.e. with land?] ecclesiastical chapters, bodies, and communities, of both sexes, and generally all clergy possessing benefice or commandery... to appear at the general assembly of their bailliage

So much for the female clergy being able to vote, so long as their order possessed a land endowment of some kind. Later, Article XI specifies that womens' orders (les chapitres et communautés de filles) would each be represented at the assembly of the bailliage (not the Estates-General!) by a single representative "taken from the ecclesiastical order" (pris dans l’ordre ecclésiastique). Article XII follows that other clergy not from orders would have to attend in person.
But for eligibility to act as a representative to either the local assemblies or the Estates-General, the rules become less clear to me, beyond that they had to come from their respective Estates. All the articles seem to deal with going to the assembly of the bailliage, not to the Estates-General, before they move on to the rules for the Third Estate.
For completeness, women of the Second Estate could vote under Article XX, if they possessed land independently (possédant divisément) and held a fief (pourvu que lesdites... possèdent des fiefs).

While I'm very skeptical that the voters would select a woman, it is an interesting question. NACMS.org includes a chart showing that religious women were roughly 25% of the first estate; it is not quite as impossible as I'd first assumed.  OTOH, I remember reading elsewhere that  the "voting" among the first estate was not entirely fair.

It is possible that there are two different uses of the term "clergy" here ; that the elections were held to represent the ordained clergy, not the administrative clergy (my terms; corrections for more precision welcome).    or it is possible that simple sexism ruled.

Thanks for helping me! I've added a link to the source of the Edict and elaborated what articles allowed women from the clergy to attend the elections.
P.S. the French Wikipedia's text links to https://books.google.fr/books?id=3LM9AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA559&lpg=PA559&dq=l%27on+entendra+par+bailliage+ou+s%C3%A9n%C3%A9chauss%C3%A9e+tous+les+si%C3%A8ges+auxquels+la+cnnaissance+des+cas+royaus+est+attribu%C3%A9e&source=bl as its source.

As for your suspicions about the elections, most of the articles about clergy talk about clergy réguliers et séculiers, where régulier meant those subject to rules (i.e. in orders) and séculier mean those living among the laity (i.e. in secular life -- curates and vicars etc.) But some rules do indeed refer only to one or the other, like Article X, which deals only with secular orders of men.

The French Wikipedia provides what looks like a complete list of deputies to the Estates General of 1789. Scanning through it, I have not yet identified any female members.
